# VS2015/vb Not Picking Up Reference

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a Visual Basic project using Visual Studio Community 2015. I need to convert an Excel spreadsheet to a PDF document. I have added the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel dll as a reference and it is showing up in my Reference list from Solution Explorer. When I look at that dll, it contains a class called Workbook. However, when I try to use this class, I'm getting a compile time error saying that this type does not exist. I'm very new to this environment and don't understand what I've forgotten to do. Here is the line of code where I'm getting the compile time error, and I will try to attach a screen print showing that I do have the dll in my references.

```
Dim myworkbook As New Workbook()[![reference list and class list within it][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use the name "Workbook" unqualified, you will need to import the namespace which contains the class:

```
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

    Dim myworkbook As New Workbook()
```

Or you could use the full name:

```
    Dim myworkbook As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook()
```